# Windows 7 prompts me to install old hotfixes

Tags: windows

I am seeing a very strange problem: yesterday, out of sudden, the windows update showed I need to install 46 important hotfixes (this does not include the optional ones) on a Windows 7 PC. I let the update run, and restarted the PC. The next day,windows update shows I need to install another 21.

I took a look at the list, some of the hotfixes are really old and should have been installed previously, e.g. KB2597126, which came out in 2012. Another example is KB2597986.

It seems some hotfixes were removed from the PC. What could be wrong?

--update--

I run get-hotfix -Id  in Powershell on them. It shows these hotfixes are not installed. But this shouldn't happen, because this PC is set to auto-install new updates.

Comment: Are the versions of the offending files on your system the same version or higher?

Comment: @GregAskew thx for your reply. They are shown as not-yet-installed. Any further thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean the files are not installed?  To be more specific, I'm asking you to look at the three files that are updated by KB2597126, and the one file updated by KB2597986, and get the version.

Comment: @GregAskew Before installing the hotfixes, the 3 excel related files were at an older version. Since now I have installed all the hotfixes, they are at the new version, e.g. 14.0.6126.5003 for excel.exe, as shown in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2597126. I will see what will come up tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

If the files replaced by the hotfix are at a lower version, the computer will be considered in-scope or relevant for the hotfix.

Comment: That's the problem - this computer is always quite up-to-date,and set to install new hotfixes automatically. For instance the excel related files would have been updated in 2012. So what went wrong?

Comment: Did you check C:\Windows\WindowsUpdate.log?